Printing Arithmetical Expressions with Akka Actors
I need to write a program that converts expressions like for example
"Add(Val(2), Add(Val(3),Val(2))" to (2+(3+2)), with the help of Actors.
The way to go is to create an Actor that sends this Expression in a Message to another Actor which then looks at the expression an create for all subexpression a left and right Actor which then repeat the process till an actor only have an expression like "Val(2)". This gets converted to an 2 and the parent Actor of this on should combine it with the other result and makes something like "(3+2)". This whole process should end then with the full String like in the example.
Its like "creating as long there are more expression != Val(int) an left and right actor and return the result in a full string". You can imagine it like a tree structure or something like that.
Now I already wrote the Code for sending the initial message and breaking down the expression with left and right actors. The only problem I have now is, storing the whole string in the right order and sending it back to the main actor. Also the Actors need to work parallel.
Here is the Code I wrote:
public class PrintActors extends AbstractBehavior<PrintActors.Message> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrintActors.class);

    public interface Message{}


    public static class PrintExpression implements Message{
        public final Expression expression;
        public final ActorRef<PrintAndEvaluateActor.Message> originalSender;

        public PrintExpression(Expression expression, ActorRef<PrintAndEvaluateActor.Message> originalSender){
            this.expression = expression;
            this.originalSender = originalSender;
        }


    }

    public static class PrintResult implements Message{
        public final String result;
        public final ActorRef<PrintAndEvaluateActor.Message> originalSender;

        public PrintResult(String result, ActorRef<PrintAndEvaluateActor.Message> originalSender){
            this.result = result;
            this.originalSender = originalSender;
        }
    }


    private PrintActors(ActorContext<Message> context){
        super(context);
    }

    public static Behavior<Message> create(){
        return Behaviors.setup(PrintActors::new);
    }




    @Override
    public Receive<Message> createReceive(){
        return newReceiveBuilder()
                .onMessage(PrintExpression.class, this::onPrintExpression)
                .onMessage(PrintResult.class, this::onPrintResult)
                .build();
    }

    private Behavior<Message> onPrintResult(PrintResult result) {
        result.originalSender.tell(new PrintAndEvaluateActor.PrintResult(result.result));
        return this;
    }





    private Behavior<Message> onPrintExpression(PrintExpression message){

        Expression expression = message.expression;
        if(expression instanceof Expression.Val){
            Expression.Val val = (Expression.Val) expression;
            getContext().getSelf().tell(new PrintResult(String.valueOf(val.inner()), message.originalSender));
        } else if (expression instanceof Expression.Add) {
            Expression.Add add = (Expression.Add) expression;
            stringifyBinaryExpression(add.left(), add.right(), "+", message.originalSender);
        } else if (expression instanceof Expression.Sub) {
            Expression.Sub sub = (Expression.Sub) expression;
            stringifyBinaryExpression(sub.left(), sub.right(), "-", message.originalSender);
        } else if (expression instanceof Expression.Mul) {
            Expression.Mul mul = (Expression.Mul) expression;
            stringifyBinaryExpression(mul.left(), mul.right(), "*", message.originalSender);
        }
        return this;
    }

    private void stringifyBinaryExpression(Expression left, Expression right, String operator, ActorRef<PrintAndEvaluateActor.Message> originalSender) {


        ActorRef<Message> leftActor = getContext().spawnAnonymous(PrintActors.create());
        ActorRef<Message> rightActor = getContext().spawnAnonymous(PrintActors.create());

        log.info("Creating anonymous left stringify actor {} and right stringify actor {} for expression: {} and {}", leftActor.path(), rightActor.path(), left, right);

        CompletionStage<PrintResult> leftFuture = AskPattern.ask(leftActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(left, originalSender), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());
        CompletionStage<PrintResult> rightFuture = AskPattern.ask(rightActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(right, originalSender), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());





        CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(leftFuture.toCompletableFuture(), rightFuture.toCompletableFuture());

        combinedFuture.thenAccept(v -> {
            try {
                String leftResult = leftFuture.toCompletableFuture().get().result;
                String rightResult = rightFuture.toCompletableFuture().get().result;
                String finalResult = "(" + leftResult + operator + rightResult + ")";


                originalSender.tell(new PrintAndEvaluateActor.PrintResult(finalResult));
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
        });
    }
}

Main problem seems to be like the try-catch part:
combinedFuture.thenAccept(v -> {
            try {
                String leftResult = leftFuture.toCompletableFuture().get().result;
                String rightResult = rightFuture.toCompletableFuture().get().result;
                String finalResult = "(" + leftResult + operator + rightResult + ")";


                originalSender.tell(new PrintAndEvaluateActor.PrintResult(finalResult));
            } catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
        });

The program never enters this one and therefore it cant really compute the full string.
And I get no Exceptions or Errors. I online get logs with the single components of the Expression. For Example for the Expression (2+(2+3) I get the output: 2 2 3

your futures never got the chance to complete, because you lost your PromiseActor(which is name as replyTo)
in this case(ask pattern) you need to pass replyTo on your message, and then the temporary actor could reply to the result(which means completed your future)
--  CompletionStage<PrintResult> leftFuture = AskPattern.ask(leftActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(left, originalSender), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());
--  CompletionStage<PrintResult> rightFuture = AskPattern.ask(rightActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(right, originalSender), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());
++  CompletionStage<PrintResult> leftFuture = AskPattern.ask(leftActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(left, replyTo), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());
++  CompletionStage<PrintResult> rightFuture = AskPattern.ask(rightActor, replyTo -> new PrintExpression(right, replyTo), Duration.ofSeconds(5), getContext().getSystem().scheduler());


